# STATIC_URL issue in django 1.5.4

Tags: python, django

I wanted to enable serving static files through django 1.5 builtin development server. I came across a strange problem.

If I make a request to my static file using `localhost:8000/static/staticstyle.css` then it responds me with `404` not found. But If I make a request to the same file without the value mentioned in the `STATIC_URL` and add the url pattern as `"url(r'^anyval_other_than_mentioned_STATIC_URL/', django.views.static.serve,{'document_setting':settings.STATIC_ROOT}), "`, then it responds me with `304` , which is conditional get.

I have collected all the static files in the static directory setup in the settings file and enabled all the context processor required for the template.

For production I have used nginx to serve the static file so there is no problem.

My settings.py looks like

```
STATIC_ROOT = APPLICATION_PATH+"/static/"

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    ('vendors',APPLICATION_PATH+'/vendors'),
    ('admin/assets/',APPLICATION_PATH+'/templates/admin/assets'),
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)
```

My application urls.py looks like

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),  
) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Any hints would be highly appreciated.

Thank you .

Comment: you can use findstatic to track down the error , https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#findstatic

Answer (score 5):

please read this first 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/static-files/

There are some settings related to static files serve
The list of finder backends that know how to find static files in various locations.

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
```

Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(APPLICATION_PATH, '..', 'static')
```

URL prefix for static files.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

You can specify Additional locations of static files

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(APPLICATION_PATH, 'vendors'),
    os.path.join(APPLICATION_PATH, '/templates/admin/assets'),
)
```

There is special application for static serve in django contrib

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    ...
)
```

After You have configured your project run `collectstatic` command

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

This will copy all files from your static folders into the `STATIC_ROOT` directory.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My settings file looks similar to the one you mentioned , but still I have the same problem. I have my settings file inside <app_dir>/settings/development.py and I export this settings before I run manage.py ,

Comment: so what is the problem You can specify settings module

Comment: Thank you so much. Been stuck on this for a few hours now!!! My Static _root wasn't absolute. Thank you :D